# How to change react-select option automatically after 5 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have created a dropdown menu in `react` using the `react-select` package, The dropdown menu is working as as expected, now I want to change the `option` value automatically after some seconds. After some seconds it should select another option from the `option array`, which option I want from the option array option.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCircle, faMinusCircle } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid";
import "./presence.css";

function Presence() {
  const [presence, setPresence] = useState({
    value: "unavailable",
    label: "Offline",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="gray" />,
  });
  console.log(presence);
  const client = useSelector((state) => state.client.client);

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setPresence(selectedOption.label);
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  const { Option, SingleValue } = components;
  const CustomSelectOption = (props) => (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5%" }}>
        {props.data.icon}{" "}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}> {props.data.label}</div>
    </Option>
  );

  const ValueOption = (props) => (
    <SingleValue {...props}>
      <span style={{ marginRight: "8%" }}> {props.data.icon}</span>
      <span>{props.data.label}</span>
    </SingleValue>
  );
  const options = [
    {
      value: "chat",
      label: "Available",
      icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="#5cd068" />,
    },
    {
      value: "xa",
      label: "Appear Away",
      icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="orange" />,
    },
    {
      value: "away",
      label: "Be Right Back",
      icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="orange" />,
    },
  
    {
      value: "dnd",
      label: "Do not Disturb",
      icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusCircle} color="red" />,
    },

    {
      value: "unavailable",
      label: "Offline",
      icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="gray" />,
    },
  ];
  const style = {
    control: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      border: 0,

      boxShadow: "none",
    }),
    placeholder: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      fontSize: "1em",
      fontWeight: 600,
    }),
  };
  const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
    return (
      components.DropdownIndicator && (
        <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={props.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? "caret-up" : "caret-down"}
          />
        </components.DropdownIndicator>
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <Select
      styles={style}
      name="presence"
      clearable={false}
      placeholder={"Choose"}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      classNamePrefix="select"
      components={{
        Option: CustomSelectOption,
        SingleValue: ValueOption,
        DropdownIndicator: DropdownIndicator,
        IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default Presence;
```

Comment: 5 seconds after what? Initial load? User interaction?

Comment: initial load .I mean after five seconds it should select another option from option array    suppose if the value selected is `{
      value: "away",
    }` after five seconds it should show `{
      value: "chat",
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code after the first render only, use `useEffect(() => {}, [])` (notice the empty array), to execute once after 5 seconds, call the `setTimeout` in the callback like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    handlerChange(options.find(o => o.value === 'chat'));
  }, 5000);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have no `value` defined on your `<Select>`
2. You have no `getOptionValue` or `getOptionLabel` defined (though it's probably using the defaults)
3. If `presence` were your `value`, all it would require is the `selectedOption.value`
4. Since `presence` appears to be defaulted to `unavailable`, then your initial `value` would never be `away`
5. You are rebuilding a lot of stuff on every rerender of `Presence`, which will force rerender your `<Select>` every time.
6. You are defaulting your `presence` to "unavailable", so it would never start as "away"

Maybe you're saying you will change the value by loading some record on component load. In that situation, you would put your `window.setTimeout` in that method. I put some notes on that in the comments below.

Refactored Presence.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCircle, faMinusCircle } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid";
import "./presence.css";

const { Option, SingleValue, DropdownIndicator } = components;
const CustomSelectOption = (props) => {
  const {
    data: { icon: Icon, label }
  } = props;
  return (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5%" }}>
        <Icon />{" "}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}> {label}</div>
    </Option>
  );
};

const ValueOption = (props) => {
  const {
    data: { icon: Icon, label }
  } = props;
  return (
    <SingleValue {...props}>
      <span style={{ marginRight: "8%" }}>
        {" "}
        <Icon />
      </span>
      <span>{label}</span>
    </SingleValue>
  );
};

const Indicator = (props) => {
  const icon = props.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? "caret-up" : "caret-down";
  return (
    <DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={icon}
      />
    </DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

const Separator = () => null;

const options = [
  {
    value: "chat",
    label: "Available",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="#5cd068" />
  },
  {
    value: "xa",
    label: "Appear Away",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="orange" />
  },
  {
    value: "away",
    label: "Be Right Back",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="orange" />
  },

  {
    value: "dnd",
    label: "Do not Disturb",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusCircle} color="red" />
  },

  {
    value: "unavailable",
    label: "Offline",
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} color="gray" />
  }
];

const style = {
  control: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    border: 0,

    boxShadow: "none"
  }),
  placeholder: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    fontSize: "1em",
    fontWeight: 600
  })
};

const getLabel = (option) => option.label;
const getValue = (option) => option.value;

function Presence() {
  const [presence, setPresence] = useState("unavailable");
  console.log(presence);
  const client = useSelector((state) => state.client.client);

  /**
   * Let's say you include some other process to 'set' `presence`,
   * like loading some record or something. The you could 'init'ialize
   * your component by then adding your timeout. You can't really do
   * this alone in a `useEffect`, as you defaulted the value, which
   * would trigger your effect.
   * 
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // make sure to check that current value again, in case
      // someone changed it in that 5 seconds
      setPresence(prev => prev === 'away' ? 'chat' : prev);
    }, 5000);
   */

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setPresence(selectedOption?.value);
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      styles={style}
      name="presence"
      isClearable={false}
      placeholder={"Choose"}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      classNamePrefix="select"
      components={{
        Option: CustomSelectOption,
        SingleValue: ValueOption,
        DropdownIndicator: Indicator,
        IndicatorSeparator: Separator
      }}
      getOptionLabel={getLabel}
      getOptionValue={getValue}
      value={presence}
    />
  );
}

export default Presence;
```